He does not need that vs He is not needing that
Consider the two expressions,

He does not need that.(lecture about empathy)


He is not needing that.

The context for the two expressions is about empathy as in he/you should be more empathetic.
Is there any difference between the two expressions?

He is not needing that is "Indian English". Offhand, I can't think of any context where a native Anglophone would ever say that. One "more emphatic" version could be He really doesn't need that. Or you could go for a more idiomatic form: He needs that like a hole in the head!

@FumbleFingers I am actually from India. Is "He is not needing that" really Indian english? I know a few quirks about Indian English(through ChatGPT), but never encountered this expression in that.

@Max IMHO it's certainly not BrE as it is normally spoken. You could also say "He won't need / be needing that."

Overuse of the continuous verb form is probably the most well-known "shibboleth" of Indian English! Probably over half of my immediate neighbours (UK South-East) were born in India / Pakistan, and whereas none of their children (born here) make the "mistake" (highly noticeable to native Anglophones), some of the parents still do it decades after settling here. It's obviously a difficult thing to "unlearn".

@FumbleFingers your comment gave me a new ChatGPT prompt. :)

Similary in the positive sense: "He needs X" vs "He is needing X".

You'd know better than me, but I believe the reason for this particlar feature of IE is that a number of Indian languages (including but not limited to Hindi) use continuous participles a lot. Other differences are that IE tends to preserve Victorian usages ("do the needful"), and promote its own neologisms ("prepone" a planned process).

See "I am having a doubt" is found in Indian English, but rare anywhere else. Rare partly because mainstream English usually pluralizes a doubt in such contexts, but mainly because we don't use the continuous in I have doubts.

@FumbleFingers I am sure "I have a question" is the correct/accepted version. "I have a doubt" just feels hilariously wrong to me, because it feels like I am saying "I doubt theory of relativity".

"have doubt"  is odd in any case. I doubt that.

@Max: I posted I have "a doubt" about whether this phrase is acceptable English here on ELL over 10 years ago. The top answer there includes One does not "have a doubt" because the singular doubt refers to a state of being. It also contains a link to an ELU question posted years before ELL even existed, pointing out that *"it does occur in Indian English". But India's a big country, so even if you live there you might not encounter all variants. So far as I'm aware, there isn't really much of a concept of "standard" Indian English.

@FumbleFingers funny enough, on one statistical software forum, people quite commonly say doubt in that sense, and I don't think all the users are Indian. Example, "doubt about the validity of maximum likelihood estimation" or similar.

@WeiwenNg: See this usage chart, showing that both There is doubt about... and There are doubts about... are far more common than I have a doubt about...,I have doubt about... Particularly when you bear in mind that NGrams are case-sensitive, so all hits for the first pair must be at the start of sentences. I'd guess that more than half the results for the second pair just happen to occur within sentences. Whatever - the bottom line is the exact way most "mainstream" Anglophones use doubt is very different to how it's often used in IE.

...I mean this usage chart.

verbs not usually used in the progressive form

Here is a list of some common verbs which are not often used in
progressive forms.
Believe, doubt, feel, imagine, know, dislike, love, hate, prefer,
realize, recognize, remember, see, suppose, think, understand, want,
wish, appear, hear, look, see, seem, smell, sound, taste, agree, deny,
astonish, disagree, impress, mean, please, promise, satisfy, surprise,
belong, concern, consist, depend, fit, involve, lack, matter, need,
owe, own, possess, weigh etc.

ALSO:

Feel does not have a progressive form when it means ‘have an opinion’.
I feel you are making a mistake. (NOT I am feeling you are making a
mistake.) See does not have a progressive form when it means
‘understand’.
I see what you mean. (NOT I am seeing what you mean.) Look does not
have a progressive form when it means ‘seem’.
She looks like she is rich. (NOT She is looking like she is rich.)
Weigh does not have a progressive form when it means ‘have weight’.
He weighs 70 kilos. (NOT He is weighing 70 kilos.)

[This may not be the whole scoop on these uses but it is a start re verbs not usually used in the progressive form.]
